# Differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Can someone please help me to prove that $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2\sin(x)}{x^2+y^2}\quad \text{if}\quad (x,y)\not=(0,0),\quad\quad f(0,0)=0$$ is not differentiable at the point $(0,0)$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried showing that it is not continuous at the origin?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Does $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}f(x,y)-\nabla f(0,0)\cdot (x,y)^T=0\ \ ?$$

Answer (score 0):

We see that $\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=1 \ $ and $\ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)=0\ $.

We choose the following norm in $\mathbb R^2$:  $\ \forall (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2 \ , \ \|(x,y)\| =\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

If $f$ was differentiable at the point $(0,0)$, we would have:

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}\dfrac{f(x,y)-f(0,0)-x\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)-y\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)}{\|(x,y)\|}=0$

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \dfrac{\dfrac{x^2\sin x}{x^2+y^2}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = 0$

And this result is false (consider for example $\ \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{x^2\sin x}{x^2+x^2}-x}{\sqrt{x^2+x^2}}$)

So, $f$ is not differentiable at the point $(0,0)$.